# How to change AndroidManifest in runtime?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Is it possible to change `AndroidManifest.xml` in runtime programatically? If it is possible, how can I change the following programatically int he AndroidManifest while running app?

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - it's not possible to change the Android `AndroidManifest.xml` in runtime.
But, you CAN do changes in runtime programatically - [**see here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) (look for `onConfigurationChanged`).

Comment: in my application there are 5 activity in which 1 activity user set the sensor is ON or OFF.means user decide the screenOrientation of on activity at run time.I already use onConfigurationChanged() method but problem is xml is reload.if set <android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> in Manifest.xml that time create a layout size problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set the configChanges attribute programmatically

Comment: Make sure before you deny an approach, even if there is a slim chance, dont ignore it, as alfasin mentioned, [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)