# Change Manifest file using code?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am working on app where I required to change manifest file.
I saw long before to change package name at time of sign apk, but not able to find that also.

so is there any way to change Version Code, Package Name and Pnermission using code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870148/change-in-androidmanifest-xml) the possible changes at runtime are very limited. At least for standard no-root-required software (Not sure though if root privileges really help for that matter). It's hard to guess what you're trying to accomplish but after all the manifest was made to fix such things as version code, package name and permissions *before* your app is compiled.
So please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: ok that's fine, your are right her...so it's for sure we ca't change it at run time, because it's all build up at compile time only.

Comment: As I said before, I don't know if rooting makes any difference. But I wouldn't count on it because that would be a major security issue.